# Scale Fit and resize not working Lottie to Xcode SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, lottie

my first question here :

( my level : 01 ( noob) )
I followed all the tutorials I found on the net about Lottie, but I can't find my solution

I try to use Lottie file inside Test project. the Lottie animation takes the whole screen, I can't make it smaller.

here is the code

```
import SwiftUI
import Lottie


struct LottieView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var animationInProgress: Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some AnimationView {
        let lottieAnimationView = AnimationView(name:"31626-e-mail")
        lottieAnimationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        lottieAnimationView.loopMode = .loop
        lottieAnimationView.play { complete in
            if complete {
                animationInProgress = false
            }
        }
        return lottieAnimationView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context : Context){
        
    }
}
```

and my ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var animationInProgress = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           
           Text("My fruit Shop").font(.title).bold()
            Image("Fruit")
                .resizable()
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
            
            if animationInProgress {
                LottieView(animationInProgress: $animationInProgress)
                    .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            Button("Like this product", action: {
                animationInProgress.toggle()
                
            })
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.accentColor)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding(.top, 50)
            
            
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

any help to understand ? I then want to put the animation in a specific place and size according to a click or an action on a button

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd suggest that you remove your last paragraph asking for tutorials (which run the risk of getting the question marked as off-topic). The first question you have is a good one and you'll have the most success here if you stick to *one* issue. Good luck!

Comment: @jnpdx hey, I deleted the last paragraph which talked about other questions about LOTTIE, thank you for your advice

Comment: It looks like Lottie already defines a class called `LottieView` so you might want to change the name of your class.   Have you tried setting the frame of the `UIView` that you are creating.  So  `lottieAnimationView.frame = CGRect(... some rect value...)` to set the frame of the UIView instead of setting the frame of the SwiftUI View?

Comment: @ScottThompson, hello Scott, thx fr your reply  I try to rename my class, and add lottieAnimationView.frame = CGRect(... some rect value...) I try to find some info about how to add a view inside a view to scale the LottieFile. nothing works.